# How to make space between two table rows smaller css

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

I'd like to have that my text and my icons are smaller to each other. They're divided in 2 rows with each 3 cells. Also, how do I make that the height and the width are responsive and don't change from squares to rectangle?

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);

html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  background: #2C3E50;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.icon{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 35px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.icon:hover, .icon:focus, .icon:active {
  box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}



.icontext{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}



table {
    border-spacing: 60px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <h1>
    <td class="icon" id="afspraken">Icoon1</td>
    <td class="icon">Icoon2</td>
    <td class="icon">Icoon3</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="icontext">Afspraken</td>
      <td class="icontext">Grenzen</td>
      <td class="icontext">Situaties</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the context in which you are implementing this so won't critique your choice of a `<table>` to lay out these icons.

It's a bad idea though to use a table cell as your icon. A better option would be to style an element inside it. I've used a `<span>` to do that [here](https://jsbin.com/yazakozaqe/1/edit?html,css,output).

```css
    html{
      height: 100%;
    }

    body{
      font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
      background: #2C3E50;  /* fallback for old browsers */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    }

    .icon{
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: block;
      -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
      vertical-align: middle;
      color: white;
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-radius: 35px;
      width: 160px;
      height: 180px;
      margin: 10px;
      line-height: 180px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    }

    .icon:hover, .icon:focus, .icon:active {
      box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }



    .icontext{
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }



    table {
        border-spacing: 60px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
      <td><a href="#" class="icon" id="afspraken">Icon1</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="icon">Icon2</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="icon">Icon3</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><a href="#" class="icontext">Afspraken</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="icontext">Grenzen</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="icontext">Situaties</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that were I to start from scratch, I would have done more things differently. To answer your question I've just made minor edits to your markup and css.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the help. I'm a starter that's probably why there are so many mistakes. I'll update it and let you know how it works.

Comment: I've updated the code in an answer. If you'd like to have the full code so you  can see the context, just ask. Thanks for the help again

Comment: Yes that's better, but still not ideal. If these icons and icontext will be clicked on to take the user to another page, then it's best that they be links (`<a>`). See my updated answer, which I have turned into a snippet you can run to view. As you can see it looks like yours, but the use of a link element instead of a form input makes it more semantically correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help bud! I changed it and it's what I want now!

Answer (score 0):

Would it be better if I did it like this?

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  background: #2C3E50;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #4CA1AF, #2C3E50); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.icon{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 35px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #007991;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #78ffd6, #007991); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.icon:hover, .icon:focus, .icon:active {
  box-shadow: 0 50px 50px -50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}



.icontext{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}



table {
    border-spacing: 60px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <h1>
    <td><input type="button" class="icon" value="Icoon1") /></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="icon" value="Icoon2") /></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="icon" value="Icoon3") /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="icontext">Afspraken</td>
      <td class="icontext">Grenzen</td>
      <td class="icontext">Situaties</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```